# Machine learning classification dataset setup

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am very sorry if this question violates SO's question guidelines but I am stuck and I cannot find anywhere else to ask this type of questions. Suppose I have a dataset containing three experimental data that were obtained in three different conditions (hot, cold, comfortable). The data is arranged in three columns in a `pandas dataframe` consisting of 4 columns (`time, cold, comfortable and hot`).
When I plot the data, I can visually see the separation of the three experiments, but I would like to do it automatically with machine learning.
The x-axis represents the `time` and the y-axis represents the `magnitude` of the data. I have read about different machine learning [classification techniques](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html)but I do not understand how to set up my data so that I can 'feed' it into the `classification` algorithm. Namely, my questions are:

1. Is this programmatically feasible?
2. How can I set up (arrange my data) so that it can be easily fed into the classification algorithm? [From what I read so far](http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/), it seems, for the algorithm to work, the data has to be in a certain order (see for example the [iris dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) where the data is nicely labeled. How can I customize the algorithms to fit my needs?
   **NOTE:** Ideally, I would like the program that, given a magnitude value, it would **classify** the value as `hot, comfortable or cold`. The time series is not much of relevance in my case

Comment: What you try to achieve using classification? if it's your data , do you have another data as test set to be classified?

Comment: Why is sorting the data not enough? Seems like you've got some XY problem here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Arman, it is my data but I would like to use the data to predict other experiment results

Comment: @alex314159 I am not sure if I understand very well your comment. Are you implying that my question is not clear enough?

Comment: Yes , it's feasible , Why not? you don't need any preprocess for using your data, but there is no conflict between the lines, you can use an easy threshold for determine new data

Comment: @Arman, how? And I think threshold are too simplistic since I will need to use the model to predict other related experimental values that value from one experiment to another

Comment: @JohnP.Smith how much experience do you have with machine learning and statistics? It may be useful to take an introductory course somewhere online.

Comment: And, generally, this type of question is much better-suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ML is used for very complicated data, you can use ML , but it does not worth it, how ever you can MLP(multi layer perceptron), but it need many prerequisite.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have much experience, you are right. I was hoping I could pick up the prerequisites through a simple tutorial. Maybe I should take a MOOC online. Thanks

Comment: @JohnP.Smith, do you want to assign a label (hot, cold, ...) to the whole time series or to individual points? can you post a sample of your data? the information you give is somewhat conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is feasible.

It's not entirely clear from the original post exactly what variables/features you have available for your model, but here is a bit of general guidance. All of these machine learning problems, from classification to regression, rely on the same core assumption that you are trying to predict some outcome based on a bunch of inputs. Usually this relationship is modeled like this: `y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 ...`, where `y` is your outcome ("dependent") variable, and `X1`, `X2`, etc. are features ("explanatory" variables). More simply, we can say that using our entire feature-set matrix `X` (i.e. the matrix containing all of our x-variables), we can predict some outcome variable `y` using a variety of ML techniques.

So in your case, you'd try to predict whether it's `Cold`, `Comfortable`, or `Hot` based on `time`. This is really more of a forecasting problem than it is a ML problem, since you have a time component that looks to be one of the most important (if not the only) features in your dataset. You may want to look at some simpler time-series forecasting methods (e.g. ARIMA) instead of ML algorithms, as some of the time-series ML approaches may not be well-suited for a beginner.

In any case, this should get you started, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Isn't ARIMA used for predicting future values as opposed to classification? In my case, the time is not relevant much. I only care about knowing if a given magnitude belongs to a hot, cold, or comfortable experiment.

Comment: So you could a) use ARIMA to forecast the value at a given time `t`, and then apply whatever rules constitute something's being `Hot`, `Cold`, or `Comfortable` (e.g. greater than 80 is "Hot") to that forecasted value, or b) treat it as a classification problem and just use `time` as your feature. There may be certain time-series components in your data (e.g. seasonality) which may require a bit more examination if you're going the ML route...

Comment: That would unfortunately not work out as I need to use the classification model to predict other experiments whose output value depends on the subjects (mice in my case) that are used.

Comment: That's a different problem entirely. If you want to forget about forecasting at all, go ahead. Have I made it clear how to approach this, in a general sense, from a machine-learning standpoint? You have some classes (`Hot`, `Cold`, and `Comfortable`) and a feature (`time`). Use `time` to predict the "class" at a given time. You can use a variety of classifiers for this. I would recommend looking at scikit-learn's [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html), too.

Comment: Thanks again. I need to have a deep understanding of machine learning and statistics to get this to work. No shortcuts I am afraid!